# How to save a compressed file of JSON instances in Python

Tags: python, json, io, compression

So I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to programming, especially reading and writing files. I programmed a function, that creates a bunch of different scenarios randomly and saves each scenario as one json file to disk. I also wrote a function, that's able to read one or multiple scenarios from those json files and works with them. So far so good, but since those json files tend to become pretty big in size, I was wondering, if there is a way to save them as one compressed file automatically. I was able to save them as a gzip file and was still able to sucessfully work with them. But I don't want to create each file as a single gzipped file, I'd like to create one single file, that contains all files, that I created in one run... like a typical zipfolder. The idea is to just create such a folder, that the user with a windows running system is able to manually extract (meaning without using python) this folder, if they're interested in the content.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: `zipfolder` is normal `zip` file but `Windows` displays it as folder. `Python` has standard module [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) so you can create `zip` file with all your files.

Comment: `zipfile` has only one problem - it can't replace file already compressed - you would have to create new zip file, add new file and copy other files from old zip file.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you're looking for [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). That let's you work with a set of compressed entries in a single that is not just like a zip file, but that actually *is* a zip file.